# WCF WebApi IQueryable doesn't work with DateTime properties

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, iqueryable, wcf-web-api

I'm unable to query any object by the DateTime properties.

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}


[ServiceContract]
public class BuildJobApi
{
    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<MyModel> GetMyModels()
    {
        return _service.GetMyModels(); // IQueryable<MyModel>
    }
}
```

I tried using WCF WebApi v0.5.0 and 0.6.0, both are throwing error messages.

Here's the URL generated (by WebApi) to query by Id (works):

```
/api/models?$filter=(Id eq 100)
```

Here's the URL generated to query by TimeStamp (doesn't work):

```
/api/models?$filter=TimeStamp ge DateTime'2012-02-22T00:00:00'
```

I can also query by date part (works):

```
/api/models?$filter=(year(ExceptionDateTime) eq 2012)
```

The exact error message is 500/Internal Server Error.  With the message:

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.
```

**Q:**  Is there anything that can be done to query the DateTime properties without querying each part separately?

Comment: Is `MyModel` marked as DataContract, and is it correct that the DateTime property is a TimeStamp?

Comment: It is not marked as DataContract.  TimeStamp is the name of the propery (for purposes of this demo), DateTime is the type.

Comment: It should be a DataContract. As for the TimeStamp - of course :).

Comment: I added [DataContract] to the class and [DataMember] to each property.  I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: Renewed the service reference? _See server logs for more details_: does that give a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid serializing `DateTime`, use string for this.

eg:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

new MyModel { Id = 123, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("o") };
```

the `"o"` is for the ISO 8601 format (culture invariant, stable format).

Comment: Well, it's been months and I still haven't been able to resolve this.  I believe DateTime may not be supported for IQueryable.  I've modified my IQuerable method to accept datetime as a string.